# string.h output words C

Tags: c, string, io, strtok, strlen

I need to compare the first and the last letter in a word; if these letters are the same, I need to output that word to a file.
But I take words from another file. My problem is i can't guess how i should output all words because in my code, it outputs only the first word. So i understand that i have no transition to others.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char my_string[256];
    char* ptr;

    FILE *f;
    if ((f = fopen("test.txt", "r"))==NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open  test file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *out;
    if((out=fopen("result.txt","w"))==NULL){
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fgets (my_string,256,f);
    int i;
    int count = 1;

    printf("My string is %d symbols\n", strlen(my_string));

    for (ptr = strtok(my_string," "); ptr != NULL; ptr= strtok(NULL," "))
    {
        int last = strlen(ptr) - 1;
        if ((last != -1) && (ptr[0] == ptr[last]))
        {
            printf("%s\n",ptr);
        }
    }

    printf("\n%s\n",my_string);
    fprintf(out,"%s\n",my_string);
    system("pause");
    fclose(f);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

In my first file there are words:

```
high day aya aya eye that
```

From my words from the first file, it outputs only the first word

```
high
```

to the second file. I expect the following:

```
high aya aya eye
```

Comment: What do you mean "it does onlythe first word"? For the specified input, what is the actual and expected output? And have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger? Do the `my_strlen` and `mystrtok` functions work as they should? *Why* do you have your own string functions instead of using the standard functions?

Comment: What's with the use of `my_strlen` and `mystrtok`? What library are you using?

Comment: It means that it outputs the first word(with the same fisrt and the same last letter) what i need but there are more than one.
my functions work. For checking i can use the library <string.h> 
i use my own functions because its a special condition for this program.

Comment: Well this code looks fine to me. I suspect the issue may lay in those custom functions.

Comment: ahah ok, but when i take these functions from the library. All the same it doesnt work:((

Comment: "doesnt work" is a pretty general description; you should explain better. For example: what does your program output? What do you expect it to output? Does it crash? Please [edit] your question and add these details. See also: [mcve]. BTW: it's good that you specified the **input** to your program. Definitely a good start.

Comment: I changed it ,now there are not my functions. 
From my words from the first file, it outputs only the word "high" in the second file. I expect for "high aya aya eye". No, it doesn't crash.

Comment: i need to think for the space in strok() , i shouldnt think about others .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not outputting anything to the file except at the very end when you fprintf the entire string:

```
fprintf(out,"%s\n",my_string);
```

You need to change `printf("%s\n",ptr);` to `fprintf(out,"%s\n",ptr);` in that for loop. Otherwise it will just output everything to the console.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now i get what i wanted. it is pretty pretty easy string but i needed in it. Ahahha thanks,thanks,thanks!!!!